# How to change or get rid of "my-suffix" in a JHipster React project?

Tags: jhipster, beta, jdl

I just started using JHipster and I am experimenting with 5.0.0-beta.1. I tried to create a simple application with React frontend.

I also tried to import a sample JDL model (The Oracle “Human Resources” sample application) described in https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/

I did a

```
jhipster import-jdl my_file.jdl
```

all went well and everyhting is working as advertised. However in the frontend all entities have a "my-suffix" suffix and even on the screen they appear as "Region My Suffix", "Country My Suffix", etc.

[image]

After reading the documentation I found the concept of "Angular suffix" and tried

```
jhipster import-jdl my_file.jdl  --force --angular-suffix=""
```

but to no avail.

So, is there a way to get rid of the suffix or set it to a meaningful value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be due to an instruction in your JDL.

The default JDL provided by JDL-studio has `angularSuffix * with mySuffix` at the end. Just remove it and import your JDL again.